# How can I avoid duplicate code in the long if-else chain?

Tags: c#-3.0

I am using web api 2 with entity frame work. On one condition I would like to know how I can reduce `if/else` for the same code. I tried so hard but I do not get any result. I am using lambada expression.

```
   //  ALL Value Is Given By User

        if (FightTypeId != 0 && Title != null && Date != null)
        {
            var getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.FightTypeId == FightTypeId && e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()) && e.Date == Date);

            //this illustrates that user can  give title in any case  and title can be in  2-3 latter of title is enough for  get output

            var res = from e in getTblEvent
                      select new
                      {
                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,


                      };
            return Ok(res);


        }

         //Only FightTypeID Is Given By User

        else if (FightTypeId != 0 && Title == null && Date == null)
        {

            var getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.FightTypeId == FightTypeId);
            var res = from e in getTblEvent
                      select new
                      {


                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,


                      };
            return Ok(res);
        }

          //TITLE Is Given By User


        else if (FightTypeId == 0 && Title != null && Date == null)
        {

            var getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()));
            var res = from e in getTblEvent
                      select new
                      {

                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,

                      };
            return Ok(res);
        }

       // Only DATE Is Given By User

        else if (FightTypeId == 0 && Title == null && Date != null)
        {

            var getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.Date == Date);
            var res = from e in getTblEvent
                      select new
                      {

                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,


                      };
            return Ok(res);
        }

        //FIGHTTYPEID And TITLE Is Given By User


        else if (FightTypeId != 0 && Title != null && Date == null)
        {

            var getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.FightTypeId == FightTypeId && e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()));
            var res = from e in getTblEvent
                      select new
                      {


                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,

                      };
            return Ok(res);
        }


         // Only DATE And TITLE Is Given By User

        else if (FightTypeId == 0 && Title != null && Date != null)
        {

            var getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e=>e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()) && e.Date==Date);
            var res = from e in getTblEvent
                      select new
                      {

                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,

                      };
            return Ok(res);
        }



        //FightTypeID And Date Is Given By User

        else if (FightTypeId != 0 && Title == null && Date != null)
        {

            var getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.FightTypeId==FightTypeId && e.Date==Date);
            var res = from e in getTblEvent
                      select new
                      {


                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,


                      };
            return Ok(res);
        }

            // by defaultly  shows all Details to user
        else
        {

            var res = from e in db.tblEvents
                      select new
                      {

                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,


                      };
            return Ok(res);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just checking the existence of each parameter, and if they aren't null (or 0) you filter by it. You can check each param once and chain `Where` calls to accomplish what you want:

```
var query = db.tblEvents;

if(FightTypeId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.FightTypeId == FightTypeId);
}

if(Title != null)
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()));
}

if(Date != null)
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.Date == Date);
}

var res = query.Select(e =>
                      new
                      {
                          EventID = e.EventID,
                          FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                          Title = e.Title,
                          Date = e.Date,
                          Location = e.Location,
                          UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                          Price = e.Price,
                          UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                          PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                          PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                          ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                          LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,
                      };

return Ok(res);
```

Comment: Error 23 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<EventManagement.Models.tblEvents>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) F:\daksh sourcetree git\EventManagement\Controllers\EventsController.cs 365 8 EventManagement

Comment: Error 23 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<EventManagement.Models.tblEvents>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) F:\daksh sourcetree git\EventManagement\Controllers\EventsController.cs 365 8 EventManagement

Answer (score 0):

You could streamline it like this:

```
   // by defaultly  shows all Details to user
   var getTblEvent = db.tblEvents;
   //  ALL Value Is Given By User

        if (FightTypeId != 0 && Title != null && Date != null)
        {
            getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.FightTypeId == FightTypeId && e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()) && e.Date == Date);
        }


         //Only FightTypeID Is Given By User

        else if (FightTypeId != 0 && Title == null && Date == null)
        {

            getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.FightTypeId == FightTypeId);
        }

          //TITLE Is Given By User


        else if (FightTypeId == 0 && Title != null && Date == null)
        {

           getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()));

        }

       // Only DATE Is Given By User

        else if (FightTypeId == 0 && Title == null && Date != null)
        {

           getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.Date == Date);
        }

        //FIGHTTYPEID And TITLE Is Given By User


        else if (FightTypeId != 0 && Title != null && Date == null)
        {

           getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.FightTypeId == FightTypeId && e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()));

        }


         // Only DATE And TITLE Is Given By User

        else if (FightTypeId == 0 && Title != null && Date != null)
        {

           getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e=>e.Title.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(Title.ToUpper().Trim()) && e.Date==Date);

        }



        //FightTypeID And Date Is Given By User

        else if (FightTypeId != 0 && Title == null && Date != null)
        {

           getTblEvent = db.tblEvents.Where(e => e.FightTypeId==FightTypeId && e.Date==Date);

        }


        var res = from e in getTblEvent
                  select new
                  {

                      EventID = e.EventID,
                      FightTypeId = e.FightTypeId,
                      Title = e.Title,
                      Date = e.Date,
                      Location = e.Location,
                      UserSelectFavoriteFlag = e.UserSelectFavoriteFlag,
                      Price = e.Price,
                      UserPredictionFlag = e.UserPredictionFlag,
                      PredictionStartDate = e.PredictionStartDate,
                      PredictionEndDate = e.PredictionEndDate,
                      ModifiedUserId = e.ModifiedUserId,
                      LastUserModifiedDate = e.LastUserModified,


                  };
        return Ok(res);
```

Comment: ya its correct but i got an error related to iqueriable since i am using ihttp action result

Comment: By the way, what's the return type of this function?

Comment: return type is ihttpactionresult

Comment: Well, the error says that an implicit conversion cannot be done, but there is an explicit conversion. So, it sounds like you need to put an explicit cast on whatever line is giving you the error. Like: (System.Linq.IQueryable<EventManagement.Models.tblEvents>)

Comment: Also, edited my answer to fix a slight error in it. I forgot to use the getTblEvent variable in the final query.

Comment: ya that i know but how to use that can u show me in code .because its still showing some error

Comment: and these code not fetching the data in exact manner  i like if  i select only date in rest client then it should shoe the detail which mapping with that date only but these code not showing my own above code perform these task perfactly

Comment: Did you use my edited version? There was a bug in my original version, which I think should be fixed now. And could you post the code section where you're getting the error? Then I could help you fix the error easier.